# Can you tell me what's wrong with " videoView.setVideoURI(uri);", " videoView.start();"?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to add video to my app. The video is locally stored in res/raw.I have no idea why I'm getting error with "videoView.setVideoURI("uri");" and "videoView.start();"

Clean build , re-build project , restart doesn't seems to be working.

`VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);`
`Uri uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.demo);`
`videoView.setVideoURI(uri);`
`videoView.start();`

[This is the code with error. I'm using android studio 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFz7j.png)
The error i'm getting with upper code is "error:  expected" for setVideoURI() and start() functions.
Please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
private VideoView video;
video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoabz;
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
video.start();
```

Luck!